# fortran: type "executable @script" in a terminal to run program using script

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran program in which I usually use scripts of commands, for example, in a terminal I write:

$program

then I enter into the program (the terminal shows "$program>") and accepts either commands or a script that I call by typing manually "@script":

$program>@script

then the fortran program opens the file named "script", which contains a series of commands or tasks that are executed.

What I want to do now is to type directly in a terminal:
$program @script

to run the program with the commands contained in the file "script".

I want to do this to be able to create sh scripts to run the program many times without having to enter into the program each time to write manually the name of each script.

Does anybody know how could I do this in fortran. I guess that the way is to start the fortran program by saying that if something was typed in a terminal after the name of the program, then the fortran program should be able to read it and use it internally. No matter which type of variable is given after typing "program", the program should be able to read it directly from the terminal. Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this:

```
program <<EOF
@script
EOF
```

Details may depend slightly on which shell you're scripting in, and on the details of the program you're trying to run.

Also, this is a shell scripting question, not much related to Fortran.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about getting Fortran to accept command line arguments.

Comment: @casey: My answer absolutely does address the question, which specifies "I want to do this to be able to create sh scripts to run the program many times without having to enter into the program each time to write manually the name of each script."  This approach does not require modifying the program, which may not even be a viable option.

Comment: And immediately following that paragraph is "Does anybody know how could I do this in Fortran.", implying he wants to address this functionality within the confines of Fortran.

Comment: @casey: the question does not project a level of expertise appropriate for taking "how could I do this in fortran" as a request for a specific implementation strategy.  What is thereafter described could be interpreted equally well as accepting command-line arguments or reading input *redirected* from the command line.  And I/O redirection is in any case a better solution for a program that already presents a text-based UI, whether the questioner thought of it or not.

Comment: Dear casey and John Bollinger, many thanks. Both answers are very good. I've tried both and they work perfectly. Since I did myself the source code I have implemented the solution proposed by casey using the get_command utility, which then allows to create more simple sh scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran 2003 defines some intrinsics that allow you to retrieve the command line arguments provided to your executable.

The functions you are interested in are `get_command_argument`, `command_argument_count` and `get_command`.

[get_command](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND.html#GET_005fCOMMAND) retrieves the entire command line.
[command_argument_count](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT.html#COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT) returns an integer with the number of arguments passed on the command line.
[get_command_argument](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html#GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT) gets the nth argument passed on the command line.

Note that this is functionality you'll need to add to your Fortran program, and if you do not have the ability to recompile it, then you cannot make this work using this approach.

In the case modifying the Fortran is not possible, then you may use programs such as [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) which let you automate input into programs that provide prompting.